# Mybatis XML - Specify table name in keyColumn attribute

Tags: spring-boot, insert, mybatis, spring-jdbc

I am using spring boot and myBatis XML mapper to perform multiple inserts into different tables. I need the autogenerated id from one of the inserts. How do I either specify a table name in the keyColumn attribute or return the "v_new_document_rev_id" variable? The following is my code and errors I get when executing:

Error:

```
15:56:51.894 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] ERROR c.t.t.m.web.util.ExceptionController - Unexpected exception occurred
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [99999]; error code [17090]; operation not allowed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:446)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.insert(SqlSessionTemplate.java:278)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:58)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy159.copyRev(Unknown Source)
    at com.ti.tmg.mtms.service.impl.ChecksheetServiceImpl.copyRev(ChecksheetServiceImpl.java:166)
    at com.ti.tmg.mtms.service.impl.ChecksheetServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$efc7573e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684)
    at com.tmg.mtms.service.impl.ChecksheetServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3bddf38.copyRev(<generated>)
    at com.tmg.mtms.web.ChecksheetController.checksheetRevUp(ChecksheetController.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.ti.tmg.mtms.config.ETagConfig$PostETagMethodOverrideHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ETagConfig.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.ti.tmg.mtms.config.ETagConfig$PreETagMethodOverrideHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ETagConfig.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getGeneratedKeys(OracleStatement.java:5219)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.getGeneratedKeys(OracleStatementWrapper.java:366)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.getGeneratedKeys(ProxyStatement.java:230)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:78)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.getGeneratedKeys(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.Jdbc3KeyGenerator.processBatch(Jdbc3KeyGenerator.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.keygen.Jdbc3KeyGenerator.processAfter(Jdbc3KeyGenerator.java:57)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:50)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:74)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doUpdate(SimpleExecutor.java:50)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:198)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:433)
    ... 128 common frames omitted
15:56:51.897 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Error getting generated key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [99999]; error code [17090]; operation not allowed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed]
```

DAO.xml:

```
<insert id="copyRev" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="checksheetId.id" keyColumn="pm_document_rev.id">
   {call
    declare

    v_new_document_rev_id  NUMBER :=0;
    v_pm_document_id       NUMBER :=0;
    v_pm_module_id         NUMBER :=0;
    v_rev_id               NUMBER :=0;
    v_id                   NUMBER;

    begin

    select pm_document_id, pm_module_id, rev_id
      into v_pm_document_id, v_pm_module_id, v_rev_id
      from pm_document_rev
     where id = #{rev_id};

    insert into pm_document_rev
     ( pm_document_id, rev_id, ecn, created_by, create_dttm, is_active, pm_module_id)
    VALUES
     ( v_pm_document_id, v_rev_id + 1, null, #{userId}, sysdate, 0, v_pm_module_id)
    RETURNING id INTO v_new_document_rev_id;

    insert into pm_document_attr_val (pm_document_rev_id, pm_document_attr_id, value)
    (select
        v_new_document_rev_id,
        pm_document_attr_id,
        value
       from pm_document_attr_val
      where pm_document_rev_id = #{rev_id});


    INSERT INTO pm_section(pm_document_rev_id,name,sort_order, parent_id, prior_rev_pm_section_id)
    (SELECT
    v_new_document_rev_id,
    name,
    sort_order,
    parent_id,
    id
    FROM pm_section
    WHERE pm_document_rev_id = #{rev_id});


    FOR section IN (SELECT id, parent_id, prior_rev_pm_section_id FROM pm_section WHERE pm_document_rev_id = v_new_document_rev_id AND parent_id IS NOT NULL)
    LOOP
    v_id := section.id;
    UPDATE pm_section
    SET parent_id = (SELECT id FROM pm_section where prior_rev_pm_section_id = section.parent_id and pm_document_rev_id = v_new_document_rev_id)
    WHERE id = v_id;
    END LOOP;

    INSERT INTO pm_section_data(pm_section_id,pm_input_sync_id,content_type,content,sort_order,parent_id,is_checksheet,input_name,prior_rev_pm_section_data_id)
    SELECT pm_sec.id, pm_sec_data.pm_input_sync_id,pm_sec_data.content_type,pm_sec_data.content,
    pm_sec_data.sort_order,pm_sec_data.parent_id,pm_sec_data.is_checksheet,pm_sec_data.input_name, pm_sec_data.id
    FROM pm_section pm_sec,
    pm_section_data pm_sec_data
    WHERE pm_sec.pm_document_rev_id = v_new_document_rev_id
    AND pm_sec.prior_rev_pm_section_id = pm_sec_data.pm_section_id;

    INSERT INTO pm_section_table(pm_section_data_id,column_id,row_id,text,content_type_id,sort_order,prior_rev_pm_table_id)
    SELECT pm_sec_data.id, pm_sec_table.column_id, pm_sec_table.row_id, pm_sec_table.text, pm_sec_table.content_type_id, pm_sec_table.sort_order,pm_sec_table.id
    FROM pm_section   pm_sec,
    pm_section_data pm_sec_data,
    pm_section_table pm_sec_table
    WHERE pm_sec.pm_document_rev_id = v_new_document_rev_id
    AND pm_sec.id = pm_sec_data.pm_section_id
    AND pm_sec_data.prior_rev_pm_section_data_id = pm_sec_table.pm_section_data_id;

    INSERT INTO pm_section_table_data(pm_section_table_id, content_type, content,sort_order, input_name, blob)
    SELECT pm_sec_table.id, pm_sec_table_data.content_type,pm_sec_table_data.content, pm_sec_table_data.sort_order, pm_sec_table_data.input_name,pm_sec_table_data.blob
    FROM pm_section      pm_sec,
    pm_section_data pm_sec_data,
    pm_section_table pm_sec_table,
    pm_section_table_data pm_sec_table_data
    WHERE pm_sec.pm_document_rev_id = v_new_document_rev_id
    AND pm_sec.id = pm_sec_data.pm_section_id
    AND pm_sec_data.id = pm_sec_table.pm_section_data_id
    AND pm_sec_table.prior_rev_pm_table_id = pm_sec_table_data.pm_section_table_id;

    INSERT INTO pm_input_config(pm_section_data_id, input_name, is_required, validation_fail_message,prior_rev_pm_input_conf_id)
    SELECT pm_sec_data.id, pm_in_config.input_name, pm_in_config.is_required, pm_in_config.validation_fail_message, pm_in_config.id
    FROM pm_section pm_sec,
    pm_section_data pm_sec_data,
    pm_input_config pm_in_config
    WHERE pm_sec.pm_document_rev_id = v_new_document_rev_id
    AND pm_sec.id = pm_sec_data.pm_section_id
    AND pm_sec_data.prior_rev_pm_section_data_id = pm_in_config.pm_section_data_id;

    INSERT INTO pm_input_validation(pm_input_config_id,ui_operator_id,value)
    SELECT pm_in_config.id, pm_in_val.ui_operator_id,pm_in_val.value
    FROM pm_section pm_sec,
    pm_section_data pm_sec_data,
    pm_input_config pm_in_config,
    pm_input_validation pm_in_val
    WHERE pm_sec.pm_document_rev_id = v_new_document_rev_id
    AND pm_sec.id = pm_sec_data.pm_section_id
    AND pm_sec_data.id = pm_in_config.pm_section_data_id
    AND pm_in_config.prior_rev_pm_input_conf_id = pm_in_val.pm_input_config_id;

    INSERT INTO pm_filter_type(pm_document_rev_id, keyword,value, prior_rev_pm_filter_type_id)
    SELECT  v_new_document_rev_id, keyword, value, id
    FROM pm_filter_type
    WHERE pm_document_rev_id =  #{rev_id};

    INSERT INTO pm_section_config(pm_section_data_id, pm_filter_type_id)
    SELECT pm_sec_data.id, f_type.id
    FROM pm_section pm_sec,
    pm_section_data pm_sec_data,
    pm_filter_type f_type,
    pm_section_config s_config
    WHERE pm_sec.pm_document_rev_id = v_new_document_rev_id
    AND pm_sec.id = pm_sec_data.pm_section_id
    AND pm_sec_data.prior_rev_pm_section_data_id = s_config.pm_section_data_id
    AND s_config.pm_filter_type_id = f_type.prior_rev_pm_filter_type_id;

    insert into pm_document_status
    (pm_document_rev_id, status, updated_by, update_dttm, is_latest, is_rejected)
    VALUES
    (v_new_document_rev_id,#{status}, #{userId}, sysdate, 1, #{is_not_rejected});


    end
    }
</insert>
```

DAO.java

```
public void copyRev(
        @Param("checksheetId") ChecksheetId checksheetId
      , @Param("status") String status
      , @Param("userId") String userId
      , @Param("is_latest") int is_latest
      , @Param("is_not_rejected") int is_not_rejected
      , @Param("rev_id") int rev_id
        );
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Override
   public int copyRev(String status, String userId, int is_latest, int is_not_rejected, int document_rev_id) {
      log.debug("called copyRev");
      ChecksheetId checksheetId = new ChecksheetId();
      checksheetDao.copyRev(checksheetId, status, userId, is_latest, is_not_rejected, document_rev_id);
      return checksheetId.getId();
   }
```

Comment: You can't. Because JDBC does not support such complex scenario. If you want to use `useGeneratedKeys`, you may have to execute the insert as a standalone statement.

Comment: Is it possible to return the variable v_new_document_rev_id from this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Oracle, `useGeneratedKeys` won't work, but you can return values as OUT parameters of a callable statement instead.

First, you need to change the `<insert />` tag as follows.

```xml
<insert id="copyRev" statementType="CALLABLE">
```

And add the following statement which sets the value of `v_new_document_rev_id` to `checksheetId.id`.

```sql
select v_new_document_rev_id into
  #{checksheetId.id,mode=OUT,jdbcType=INTEGER} from dual;
```

Here is a small executable demo project.
https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-66377098